# Visual Studio editor go to next or previous sub o function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm starting with Visual Studio 2015 and have a question in Code Editor when using large Sub or Function in vb.net.

I would like navigate fast to the start or End of the actual Sub/Function.
Also I would like later return to the previous point....

I remember in vb6 you would use Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn to navigate between Subs/Functions.

There is some hotkeys availables in vs editor?

For example, you are in the middle of an very large Sub and you need to type some code at start or end and after this return to the actual point.

Sorry if the question is so novice, and sorry my poor English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be compatible to the answer in this Question reg. VS 2010?

[Keyboard shortcut to move cursor between methods in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127547/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-cursor-between-methods-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks, I used the find with several topics but don't found this.
The real solution (refactor) is very expensive for me, i Will try to test the others, as the one from stakx, but maybe not the nice solution because I want also return to the point (I think I can resolve this with a marker...)